# Javascript redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

There is this line in a javascript code that i downloaded which is preventing my links from working properly. Instead of linking to my index page, it links to the source where i downloaded the code even though i've pointed it to redirect to the index page. it makes all the links on the page redirect to the source i downloaded the code. how do i change it to make my links work normally.

```
var aa=li.getElementsByTagName("a");
if(aa.length>0) { 
    li.className=li.className;
    li.style.position="static";
    aa[0].href="http://source_code.com/"
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove it?

Comment: Why're you keeping that line?

Comment: It's this part: `.href=` Remove the line as it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: removing .href= made it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it is doing nothing except generating error, missing closing braces is one of that error:

```
var aa=li.getElementsByTagName("a");
if(aa.length>0){
  li.className=li.className;
  li.style.position="static";
  aa[0].href="http://source_code.com/";

 }// add closing braces here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set href using 
`aa[0].setAttribute("href","http://source_code.com/");`